# Detrended Cross Correlation, how sensitive is it to structural break and seasonality?

Tags: stationarity, seasonality, cross-correlation

Is Detrended Cross Correlation(DCC) sensitive to structural break and seasonality? I learned that the approach is for non stationary time series, but I cannot find any information about whether its vulnerable to structural break, seasonality or any type of non stationarities.

What should I check before deciding whether to use this approach?

Lastly, other than that DCC is better in non stationary series, what exactly is the difference between DCC and Cross Correlation? Can it be used to see if two different movements with one having a time lag are similar like Cross Correlation?